# Not able to parse JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a probably quite simple to solve problem. I'm trying to parse this JSON file using jquery:

http://pastebin.com/c14G0mJ1

My jQuery code looks like that:

```
$.post("/xhr/fav_switch", {event_id: event_id}, function(data) {
    event = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(event.pk);
});
```

but no matter which field i'm trying to access in alert, it allways says `undefined`. have you any idea what am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can't you debug the JS and figure out what **IS** inside "event"

Comment: i've tried but the alert was saying that it's an Object, not the array

Comment: The alert will always show it as an object.  But you can attach an actual debugger were you can put a breakpoint in and check all the "guts" of the object.  Something like Visual Studio or even FireBug.  http://getfirebug.com/errors

Comment: thank you, i'm not very familiar with javascript but i'll try to debug  my code that way in the future ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post("/xhr/fav_switch", {event_id: event_id}, function(data) {
    var events = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var event = events[0];
    alert(event.pk);
});
```

You get an array (with one element) back, so event is an array. You need to get the first element of the array to get to the event object itself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your data is an array with exactly one element, so you need to access it as:

```
event[0].pk
event[0].fields.updated
// etc
```

But also jQuery ajax methods usually parses the JSON for you so you may find you can just say:

```
data[0].pk
data[0].fields.updated
```

*without* needing to use `event = jQuery.parseJSON(data)`.